# Make <body> and <html> tags be 100% of the page

Tags: html, css

I know, it might be a dumb question, but I am really stuck with it now :(

So, I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div.main>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding CSS code:

```
html {
  height: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  min-width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;

  background: url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

You may see it here: [right here](http://7t.resynx.lv/503h)

So, the `body` tag now is about 1300 px in height, but `html` tag is a bit smaller. It is the most strangest thing I have ever seen in my beginner's experience, so I would be very grateful if you could explain me what is going on.

Tryied to Google it, but all the people says is to add `height: 100% !important` to `body` tag and that's all. Well, it is not working for me :(

Comment: What is the problem, and what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying the get the background to reach the bottom of the page?

Because then you can just do `background: #000000 url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat;`

Your problem here, is not the height of the tags, but the height of the image, which you have set NOT to repeat. And therefore you have to set a background-color behind the image.

Comment: Yes, sure. I want a background to reach the bottom, but I do not know what else should I do. Setting this background really helps, thank you for that!

Comment: But why can't I stretch `body` tag to make it reach the bottom?

Comment: Your body-tag stretches automatically, unless you're using overflow: hidden, which you are not. So there really is no problem with the heights. Your background-image just isn't high enough, which is why you should set a background-color as well :)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I completely forgot that I have a static image, not a texture, as usual.

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark the post as an answer, to help other people in the community :)